# Java : Generic method and return type

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone explain what does the return type mean in the following code

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> a()
{       
       return null;
}
```

and

```
public static <String> ArrayList<Vector> a()
{       
       return null;
}
```

Comment: I typed those code in Eclipse. It probably doesn't make sense, but it doesn't give a compiler error

Comment: @BheshGurung It gives a compile warning, but no compile errors.

Comment: It's called a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: In the second example you are doing two things you probably don't want to do. Firstly you are defining a general parameter named `String` which is also the simple name of a popular class and doesn't follow the naming convention of all caps (actually one cap, but I sometimes like more - `EXC` for exception types `THIS` for `Enum` like things). Also you've use a raw form of a generic, `Vector`. Worse you've used a raw form in a generic - a "rare type" (not like steaks). (Oh, by convention, add a space after the `>` for the generic parameter list - the parameters aren't part of the return type.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> a()
```

The first occurance of `<T>` introduces a type parameter which will be available within the method.

The actual return type is `ArrayList<T>`, where `T` is same as the one in the first.

You can read about it here - [Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

In the second one:

```
public static <String> ArrayList<Vector> a() {
```

Even though you have introduced a generic type parameter (i.e. `String`, which is not an actual type or argument like `java.lang.String`) you are not using it. And, also the method always returns an `ArrayList<Vector>` (`ArrayList` of `Vector`s).

Comment: The addition of the space makes it much less confusing, IMOHO. (Although I think the C#/Scala syntax -- where the generic types are introduced *after* the method name is better planned overall.)

Comment: Yes, and also the OP seems to be confused about the type parameter and argument.